# Laravel 5 - change default log location, move log file outside the app

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, error-logging, error-log

How can I change default log file location `<project-name>/storage/logs/laravel.log` to  something like `/var/logs/<project-name>/laravel.log`?

Comment: Take a look at http://laravel.io/forum/02-06-2015-laravel5-how-to-change-logs-path - Appears to have a solution

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I resolved this case by using [`errorlog`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) logging model and configuring webserver.

**1. Configure Laravel:**

In `config/app.php` configuration file:

```
'log' => 'errorlog'
```

Read more about Laravel log configuration: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors#configuration

**2. Configure webserver (in my case Nginx):**

```
error_log    /var/log/nginx/<project_name>-error.log;
```

Answer (score 6):

For those who don't want to use `errorlog` and just really want to replace the file to log to, you can do this:

```
\Log::useFiles(env('APP_LOG_FILE'), config('app.log_level', 'debug'));
$handlers = \Log::getMonolog()->getHandlers();
$handler = array_shift($handlers);
$handler->setBubble(false);
```

on `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php` or any `Provider` for that matter. This will log to the value of `APP_LOG_FILE` instead of the default `laravel.log`. Set bubbling to true and the application will log on both files.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still coming across this post in hopes of changing their log file location, I believe this is now easier in newer versions of Laravel. I am currently using 8.x

In your `/config/logging.php` you can define the `path` for your single and daily logs. Just update whichever one your are looking to change. Just make sure you also include the name of the log file, not just the path to where you'd like it saved.

```
'single' => [
    'driver' => 'single',
    'path' => "/your/desired/log/path/file.log", // edit here
    'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
],

'daily' => [
    'driver' => 'daily',
    'path' => "/your/desired/log/path/file.log", // edit here
    'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
    'days' => 14,
]
```