# Laravel logs to error_log?

Tags: php, laravel, logging

All logs from Laravel goes to storage/logs. Unfortunatelly I don't have access to this directory. I can't even check if there are any files or read them. I can only request logs which won't give me those files. I'll get error_log, acces_log etc. but not Laravel logs.

Is there any way to force laravel to use error_log($message) for any logs/exceptions?

Comment: check here , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33825978/laravel-5-change-default-log-location-move-log-file-outside-the-app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [laravel-log-viewer](https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer).

### Install (Laravel)

#### Install via composer

```
composer require rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer
```

Add Service Provider to config/app.php in providers section

```
Rap2hpoutre\LaravelLogViewer\LaravelLogViewerServiceProvider::class,
```

Add a route in your web routes file:

```
Route::get('logs', '\Rap2hpoutre\LaravelLogViewer\LogViewerController@index');
```

Go to http://myapp/logs or some other route

Optionally publish log.blade.php into /resources/views/vendor/laravel-log-viewer/ for view customization:

```
php artisan vendor:publish \
  --provider="Rap2hpoutre\LaravelLogViewer\LaravelLogViewerServiceProvider" \
  --tag=views
```

> If you got a InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php error, it
>   may be a problem with config caching. Double check installation, then
>   **run php artisan config:clear**.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This actually doesn't answer exactly on my question however it's much better solution.

Answer (score 5):

laravel log has four available settings :  "single", "daily", "syslog", "errorlog";

you can change it on /project_root/config/app.php  or .env

I think it will solve your problem if you set 'log' => "syslog".

Comment: I think laravel should have better documentation. I saw those options but there is no explanation how they work.

Comment: Your answer may answer my question but I accepted the one which solves my problem in better way.